# Redis Docker not linking with other docker containers

Tags: docker, redis

I have two docker images. One is jobservice and another one is redis. I tried to link the redis container into my job service container by using link command.

The error is unable to find the docker image.

I removed the link command then it is working fine.

Two docker images

```sh
$ docker images ls
gcr.io/sighmo-development/jobservice                1.0.1               f0a1a4458f89        11 seconds ago      874MB
redis                                               latest              f7302e4ab3a8        2 weeks ago         98.2MB
```

Docker ps command

```sh
$ docker ps
848cf2992a34    redis    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 hours ago         Up 8 hours    6379/tcp   some-redis
```

docker command to run jobservice

```sh
$ docker run -d \
    --env-file /home/amareswaran_cloud/lookmyjobs-repo/LOOK_MY_JOBS/docker-env/env.list \
    -v /home/amareswaran_cloud/lookmyjobs-volume/jobservice:/home/ssl --name=jobservice \
    --link discovery:discovery \
    --link sc_kafka:kafka \
    --link scdb:scdb \
    --link sc_redis:some-redis \
    gcr.io/sighmo-development/jobservice:1.0.1
```

Expected is docker command should link with redis. But actual is docker image not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the container name and alias reversed. The container name should be first, and according to `docker ps`, your container is named `some-redis`:

```
--link some-redis:sc_redis
```

Comment: docker link is deprecated, better suggest the use of network commands

Comment: "It works" is not enough, you have to consider also the deprecation path provided by the maintainers... And it's going to be deprecated in favor of Networks

Answer (score -1):

Seems you're running different containers, not arranged by a `Compose` file and I strongly suggest you to use it for a several number of reasons:

1. you can achieve IaC (Infrastructure as Code) and commit it in a human-readable form
2. you can highly reproduce it just with a single command (`docker-compose up`), along with tear down (`docker-compose down`)
3. you can use with ease Docker *network* in order to avoid the use of *link* feature that is [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/)

In the end, it looks I'm missing some useful information to translate your current deployment to a *Compose*-based reference (I'm referring to `sc_kafka`,`scdb` and `sc_redis`), so YMMV but it should work enough adding required services.

First of all, ensure you got installed [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) in your path and put the content of this file in your working directory (I suppose `/home/amareswaran_cloud/lookmyjobs-repo`).

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
  sc_kafka:
    image: <KAFKA_IMAGE>
  scredis:
    image: <REDIS_IMAGE>
  scdb:
    image: <DB_IMAGE>
  jobservice:
    image: gcr.io/sighmo-development/jobservice:1.0.1
    env_file:
    - ./LOOK_MY_JOBS/docker-env/env.list
    volumes:
    - ./../lookmyjobs-volume/jobservice:/home/ssl
```

With this simple `Compose`, all containers are linked to each one, just need to use the `{SERVICE_NAME}` DNS name and there you go.

An additional feature could be to set up several networks in order to segregate services at its best but that's a next step you can achieve on your own later.